# Downloading intraday data for AEX future from investing.com via Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

My goal is to have 1-minute candle data for the AEX future available in Python. First, a historical dataset to backtest, later on, live data.

I've tried using InvestPy, but this doesn't give any intraday historical rates. The AEX future is also not available on Yahoo Finance, that would have made it very easy.

So I am looking into possibilities to scrape it from the Investing.com website. I saw some SO posts to do so and [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64476984/how-do-i-scrape-data-from-investing-com) seemed to be helpful.

However, I can't get it to work for AEX Futures.

This is the code from that OS. I don't know where to obtain the 'URL' part. I found the below URL by digging in the "Inspection page" then "Network" tab on Chrome. It does give me some data on the AEX, but no quotes or candles or anything.

I have updated the 'referer' part with the page I want the data from.

```python
import json
import datetime
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://tvc4.investing.com/53ec64967b82eb6e28595146e26b6579/1643213764/1/1/8/symbols?symbol=N25'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://nl.investing.com/indices/netherlands-25-futures'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print( json.dumps(data, indent=4) )

for candle in data['candles']:
    t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(candle[0] // 1000)
    print('{!s:<20} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(t, *candle[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

here the solution: read the initial comments where I explain how to do
You can also find all the ID here

https://sites.google.com/site/amibrokerplugins/investing_com_realtime_amibroker_data_plugin

the push the botton "SymbolInfo files only"

---

`enter code here`
import json
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
# https://it.investing.com/indices/netherlands-25-futures
# ID for the future = 8878
# to find you must search : setTargeting("pair_id",
# and after the comma you will find "8878"
# then change the id in the url


url = 'https://it.investing.com/common/modules/js_instrument_chart/api/data.php?pair_id=8878&pair_id_for_news=8888&chart_type=area&pair_interval=300&candle_count=120&events=yes&volume_series=yes&period='
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://it.investing.com/indices/netherlands-25-futures'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print( json.dumps(data, indent=4) )

print("##################################################################")
#print("Inizio candele" )
for candle in data['candles']:
    t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(candle[0] // 1000)
    print('{!s:<20} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(t, *candle[1:]))
```